# Perform advanced queries on data stored in Azure Tables (DW? MR?)

Tags: azure, data-warehouse, azure-table-storage

We are an adtech company and we store a large amount of data in Azure Tables. Things like page views, page actions, sessions etc for each user. The reason we chose Azure tables over SQL Server is the sheer volume of data (tens of thousands every second).

We are looking to take this one step further and perform advanced queries on that data. Is this somehow possible in the Azure ecosystem? Maybe through loading the data in their Data Warehouse offering or through some Map Reduce queries?

In addition, if the above is possible we were also thinking to ingest data in micro-batches in the data warehouse to make sure we have a relatively fresh copy and not have to load huge batches. Is this something Azure supports?

Thanks

Comment: This is a fairly broad question. If you're talking about queries aside from the ones Table Storage offers, then how you transfer data to a different processing engine is really up to you (there is no built-in engine such as map/reduce in Azure Storage). As far as data ingestion: Probably lots of ways, but again, this is really broad and open ended. And will likely turn into a discussion. You should consider writing specific questions.

Comment: From you question description what i can suggest is you should try looking into the "Azure DataFactory" and then pipe it to "HDInsight or Data Lake Store" for analytics.

Answer (score 0):

With Azure Tables you can query the data using query operators like these: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd135725.aspx
You could build your custom application using Azure Table capabilities for deeper analysis.

Alternatively, if you are interested in doing big data analysis with your data, by within Azure using an existing software framework, consider HDInsight or Data Lake Analytics. It offers more sophisticated. 
HDInsight: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/hdinsight/
Data Lake Analytics: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/data-lake-analytics/ 
Each analytical engine will have means for data ingestion.